# MySQL Alter table strange key error

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench to create a large database.

I keep getting:

> ERROR: Error 1089: Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys

When trying to execute the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `view4`.`entities` DROP COLUMN `resellerType` ,
DROP COLUMN `industrTypeId` ,
DROP COLUMN `paymentTermsId` ,
ADD COLUMN `paymentTermsId` INT(11) NOT NULL  AFTER `vatRateId` ,
ADD COLUMN `industrTypeId` INT(11) NOT NULL  AFTER `paymentTermsId` ,
ADD COLUMN `resellerType` INT(11) NOT NULL  AFTER `industrTypeId` ,
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_entities_grades1`
```

I have tried changing the length of various INT columns but it has no effect. I am also getting this error on a few other tables.

What is workbench doing wrong?

---

I've reduced it a bit to:

```
ALTER TABLE `view4`.`entities` DROP COLUMN `resellerType` ,
DROP COLUMN `industrTypeId`  , 
ADD COLUMN `industrTypeId` INT(11) NOT NULL  AFTER `paymentTermsId` ,
ADD COLUMN `resellerType` INT(11) NOT NULL  AFTER `industrTypeId`
```

and it's still giving me the error.

Comment: "*What is workbench doing wrong?*" - You mean it works in the mysql console? =)

Comment: Split sentence into small pieces. Isolate error.

Comment: I believe the issue is you are trying to drop a column 'paymentTermsId' (and one more) and you are asking mysql to add a column after 'paymentTermsId' (and one more). What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Reno Jones It doesn't work in any console, so it is workbench doing things in the wrong order? What would be a work around?

Comment: Can you add your columns first and then drop them in a different query? This will do the job for you.

Comment: @Reno Jones That gives me a duplicate column error. Please see edit.

Comment: Do you have 'industrTypeId' in your DB already? Apparently, do all the dropping of columns in a different query and do all addition of columns in a different query. You are doing two things at a time on the same column man. I hope you understand the issue. :)

Comment: Are you able to solve now?

Comment: @Reno Jones No. If I drop all my tables from the DB, how can I just upload the whole database again so it omits the DROP directives?

Comment: Via Commandline - $mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < yourdatabase.sql..  If you are using Wamp/Mamp, go to phpmyadmin -> databases -> import -> Browse -> Go :)

Comment: I just dropped all the tables and imported the model to any source, chose the database and it worked well. It used CREATE TABLE instead of ALTER this time so there were no conflicts with existing columns etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you changed indexed field type from CHAR/VARCHAR to INT, used index was created with prefix length. The script recreates this field - DROP COLUMN + ADD COLUMN, and this causes an error.

Try to alter fields using this way -

```
ALTER TABLE `view4`.`entities`
  CHANGE COLUMN `industrTypeId` `industrTypeId` INT(11) NOT NULL
    AFTER `paymentTermsId`,
  CHANGE COLUMN `resellerType` `resellerType` INT(11) NOT NULL
    AFTER `industrTypeId`;
```